# Pywinauto TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, pywinauto

Hello I faced a problem:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application.start(cmd_line="C:\Folder\Wow.exe")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What shall I add to code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate the Application object and call start on that, not on the class. As [the documentation](http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#entry-points-for-automation) shows:

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start('notepad.exe')
```

In your case I guess you need the win32 backend, so:

```
app = Application(backend="win32").start(cmd_line="C:\Folder\Wow.exe")
```

Comment: `backend="win32"` is a default option for now. Might be switched to `backend="uia"` since it covers much more applications.

Answer (score 1):

app = Application().start(cmd_line="C:\Folder\Wow.exe")

Comment: Glad it works! Please note the backend setting that Daniel mentioned.