# "TypeError: Start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I do not understand what "TypeError: Start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" means. I require clarification about what this error message refers to and what is required to fix it.

While [this other Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705452/pywinauto-typeerror-start-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self) question answers about the "need to instantiate the Application object and call start on that, not on the class", I have absolutely no clue what this explanation implies using as simplest of language possible. What kind of code fixing is specifically required to fix this kind of error?

The program that I am making also has this kind of error, but I don't know where exactly in my program is making this error; when I press my custom-made record button, it shows the following error:

`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

My program does not have 1699 lines; it only has about 128 lines. Here is my entire program, with the approximately 128 lines to show you it does indeed not have 1699 lines as well as to show you my program that contained this confusing error:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import time

class TimeCheck():
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0              

    def trianglemove(move_x, move_y):
        canvas.move (triangle3, move_x, move_y)

    def _update(self):
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                  

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1
            print ("RECORD")
            #for recordcounter in range(768):
            trianglemove(1, 0)

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)    

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

timechecker = TimeCheck(root)

recordbutton = PhotoImage(file="images/recordbutton.gif")
beatbutton = PhotoImage(file="images/beatbutton.gif")
stopbutton = PhotoImage(file="images/stopbutton.gif")

label_toptitle = tk.Label(root, text="Program Name", font=(None, 40),)
label_toptitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)

description = "To create rhythm, press the red record button. While recording, use the clicked note button to\n create a series of rectangle notes on screen. They can be held to extend the rectangles. \n\n Once you are done, press the red stop button to stop recording"

pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
label_desc = tk.Label(root, image=pixel, compound="center", width=900, font=(None, 14),
                                          padx=20, pady=10, text=description)

label_desc.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width=960, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

for linecounter in range(49):
        newtextbit = linecounter + 1
        if (newtextbit + 3) % 4 == 0 and newtextbit != 49:
                #print ('x is divisible by 3')
                canvas.create_text((linecounter * 16 + 80), 90,
                                           fill="darkblue",
                                           font="Times 10 bold",
                                           text=newtextbit)
        if (newtextbit + 3) % 4 == 0:
                canvas.create_line(((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 40, ((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 70,
                                           width=1,
                                           fill="black"
                                           )
        else:
                canvas.create_line(((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 50, ((linecounter * 16 + 80)), 70,
                                           width=1,
                                           fill="black"
                                           )
canvas.create_line(73, 70, 860, 70,
                                   width=2,
                                   fill="black"
                                   )
triangle3 = canvas.create_polygon(75, 25, 86, 25, 80, 40, fill ='red')

f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=70, height=30)
f1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')

button_record = tk.Button(f1,
                                                text="Record",
                                                image=recordbutton,
                                                command=TimeCheck.Start,
                                                compound="top"
                                                )
button_beat = tk.Button(f1,
                                                text="Beat",
                                                image=beatbutton,
                                                #command=tomato,
                                                compound="top"
                                                )
button_playstop = tk.Button(f1,
                                                text="Stop",
                                                image=stopbutton,
                                                #command=potato,
                                                compound="top"
                                                )

button_record.pack(side='left', padx=140)
button_beat.pack(side='left', padx=55)
button_playstop.pack(side='left', padx=140)

root.mainloop()
```

The aim of the my program is to make that red needle move rightwards at a specific rate upon pressing the Record button. However, that specific area of the program keeps giving me the error that I reported near the top of this page.

Comment: The error is because in your button command `TimeCheck.Start` you are calling the function without instantiating a `TimeCheck` object. It is expecting `self` to be passed in which happens for class methods when you create an instance of that object.

Comment: What are your suggestions of fixing this?

Comment: You have to pass in an initialized object of your `TimeCheck` class to the command argument. I gave an example in my answer.

Comment: Your question will be better if you remove all of the code that isn't related to the problem. For example, you can remove two of the three buttons, all of the images, and several other bits of code. See [mcve].

Comment: It is difficult to know which part of the code is causing such problem. If I knew which part of the code in particular was causing the issue, I would've tooken out those irrelevant bits of code.

Comment: Well I suppose two of the three buttons and all of the images would be redundant for this question, but as for the other bits of code, I think those parts are pretty uncertain as to what bit of the code is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is telling you the error occured on line 1699 is because the error occured when Tkinter tries to call your function specified in the `command=TimeCheck.Start` argument. So the error is occuring inside of Tkinter's module code, but caused by how you passed in the arguments.

You need to create an instance of the `TimeCheck` class before calling the non static methods inside of it. The message is telling you the `self` parameter expected for the `Start` function was not passed in, which happens behind the scenes in Python when you call a function on an instantiated object.

All you need to do is make your button command parameter be like this:

```
button_record = tk.Button(f1,
                          text="Record",
                          image=recordbutton,
                          command=timechecker.Start,
                          compound="top")
```

Where `timechecker` is the already instantiated TimeCheck object to call the `Start` function from.